# entitymanagerfactory is closed in hibernate

Tags: entitymanagerfactory

## hibernate query is being executed once after that it is showing error - EntityManagerFactory is closed

```
public List getHQLQuery(String HQLQuery){
Session session=factory.openSession();
if(session!=null){
Transaction tx=null;
List list=null;
try{
tx=session.beginTransaction();
list=session.createQuery(HQLQuery).list();
tx.commit();
}
catch(HibernateWxception e){
if(tx!=null)
tx.rollback();
e.printstackTrace();
}
finally{`your text`
session.close();
}
retrun list;
}
return null;
}
```